# PHP Objects trying to Access an external array

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have an Object that needs to access a previously declared array in my statistics. I can of course create the entire array inside of the object, but since multiple objects use the exact same array there is no reason to clog up memory or time by making a call to the Database to create the same array every time I create a new object.

So, I understood that Objects cannot access global variables, but is there any work-around to access an external Array from within the object?

example Code:

```
global $stats = array();
       $stats[1]['value']= 10;
       $stats[1]['value1'] =2;
       $stats[2]['value']= 12;
       $stats[2]['value1'] =1;

class Obj() {

  private $valueA;
  private $valueB;

  function __construct($user) {
    //access Database lets call $SQL;
    $valueA = SQL->value;

  }

  function showA() {
    return ( $valueA * $stats[1]['value1']) + $stats[1]['value'];
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you pass the array as an argument in a method like `setArray()` in the object?

Comment: Your question, prompted me to understand that I wrote the question wrong, I editted the question.. and in that, understood a possible solution.

In Essence, I don;t want to store the array values in the object, I only wish to know the results of the object + array ..

So, why not change the function 'showA()' to showA($stats), so the object returns the values, WITH the arrays values calculated at the time of execution, and not storing the aray in the object.

Thanks for Rubber Ducking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike, Sheikh and Kristian,

I can't in all Faith give a tick to your answers, because your words did not help me to understand the answer, Putting 'global $stats;' into the class results in an Error which I pointed out in my responses. but I will 'up' your scores when I permission from the site to do so.

For anyone looking for the answer to this, a Reminder, the key point is not to store the entire Array in the class, creating a huge waste of memory. The Key point is to gain access to the Variable which exists outside of the class.

While adding access to the global $stats by including it in the functions of the class, does produce the required results, It still requires that the Data is being stored in the class, which is again, against the point. Sorry I wasn't clear on this from the very beginning.

Instead:

example Code:

```
 function showA(&$stats) {
   return ( $valueA * $stats[1]['value1']) + $stats[1]['value'];
 }
```

}

This, if I understand correctly, will use the pointer to the $stats variable, only within the scope of returning the $valueA after it has been modified using the stats array. not copying the entire array into another memory location, nor the class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes how about changing your class to look like this:

```
class Obj() {

  private $valueA;
  private $valueB;
  private $stats;

  function __construct($user, $stats) {
    $this->stats = $stats;
    //access Database lets call $SQL;
    $valueA = SQL->value * $this->stats[1]['value1'] + $this->stats[1]['value'];
    $valueB = SQL->value * $this->stats[2]['value1'] + $this->stats[2]['value'];
  }

  function showA() {
    return $valueA;
  }

}
```

You than just pass `$stats` to the object at instantiation. Or if you don't want it in the constructor, just make a `setStats($stats)` method that does the same.

Comment: Either way, The entire array is being stored in the object. But your post helped me to take the next thought to process..

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you three ways to do this:

1. pass the array into the constructor of the class. e.g.: `$myObject =
   new Obj( $stats );`
2. make a class that serves up the `$stats` array: `$stats = new Stats(); $statsArray = $stats->getStats();`
3. use the term `global` inside of a public method in your class itself (not construct) to get that variable:  3:

   ```
   function() somePublicMethod() {
       global $stats;
       $valueA = SQL->value * $stats[1]['value1'] + $stats[1]['value'];
       $valueB = SQL->value * $stats[2]['value1'] + $stats[2]['value'];
   }
   ```

Comment: 3. you cannot put a global in the class, you get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_FUNCTION

BUT as noticed, you can put it in the function in the class

Comment: yes thats right, my bad. i do use global in a class method for only one type of thing: grabbing a `$config` variable from a bootstrap or an external config file

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables from within a class, i.e.

```
$stats[1]['value']= 10;
$stats[1]['value1'] =2;
$stats[2]['value']= 12;
$stats[2]['value1'] =1;

class Obj {
    var $myStats;
    function __construct() {
        global $stats;
        $this->myStats= $stats;
        print_r($this->myStats);
    }
}

$obj=new Obj; // Array ( [1] => Array ( [value] => 10 [value1] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [value] => 12 [value1] => 1 ) )
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7hx203).

Comment: ahh, you mean you can access globals from within a FUNCTION, but when I wrote the global in the class it gives me the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_FUNCTION

Comment: Ahh, I do now, but its not loading. Time out error. (putting just one word in a different colour wasn't noticable)

Comment: This is an awful design pattern should be avoided.

Comment: @BenStephenson, I agree that globals are evil, this just an assumption that could be used as an alternative but definitely it's not recommended and anti-pattern, at least, now in a day, where we are using dependency container in our applications.

Comment: @BenStephenson, Also, I would like to remind you that, it was not my idea, OP used it in his question and I've just showed him how to access his global array from within his class. This is not about design pattern, instead, it's how to access a glob a array from within a class.